# How to set a fixed localhost address for X11 forwarding?

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, pycharm

I have a remote ubuntu server that is used by multiple users for development. We use PyCharm connected to the server as a remote interpreter.

In order to use X11 forwarding in PyCharm you have to set the DISPLAY env-variable in the project config (for instance: localhost:10.0).

However when working with multiple users on the same server, this address changes from time to time depending on who is working at the time you login, while PyCharm is still using the 'fixed' env-variable.

Is there a way to 'fix' the assignment of the localhost addresses at the serverside per user, so that user1 always gets localhost:10.0, user2 localhost:11.0, etc., regardless of whether other users also being logged on?

Thanks a lot!